# How set ChrootDirectory on ssh_config in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: ssh, openssh, chroot

how can I set the chroot directory for a specific user in ssh_config?

I'm trying:

```
Match User zeus
      ChrootDirectory /home/test
      Forwardx11 no
```

But I get a syntax error for the "ChrootDirectory" setting.

Comment: AFAIK that setting is only valid in the `sshd_config` (it wouldn't really make sense for SSH clients to be able to control a user's chroot directory)

Comment: You're right. I'm a newbie with Linux and I was trying to modify the incorrect file. Thanks!